# Modifying css search-toolbar

Tags: css, asp.net

I am trying to create a page with a search bar and filters underneath. I really like the way the search-toolbar looks, but it's creating space that I don't need. Is there a way to modify i to get rid of the space?

Thanks!

Here's an image of what I have:
[Search bar with toolbar underneath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92yfK.png)

Edit: That grey space is what I'm trying to get rid of.

Here's my asp code:

```
    <div class="search-toolbar" style="background-color:white">
        <ul class="list-unstyled nav nav-pills">         
                <li>
                    <a href="#everything" data-toggle="tab">Everything</a>
                </li>
                 <li>
                   <a href="#everything" data-toggle="tab" onclick="searchProvider()">Other Content</a>
                 </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            Content
        </div>
```

Comment: What's your relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I found the css file and edited it. 
I'm still new to web development, and I wasn't aware that I could do that.